# Publish .NET Core website as a single executable file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, .net-core

I'm using a "ASP.NET Core with React.js" template in Visual Studio. I've configured publish process to produce a single file. While it does package all the .NET files into one executable, it still generates a separate "ClientApp" folder that contains a build of a React App.

Is there a way to embed everything inside the executable? Like, copy everything inside .zip archive, embed it as a resource and host everything from there.

I am trying to add a UI to a background service. So that a user could open a page in theirs browser and check service status. Frameworks like Electron will not work for me, as the service should be accessible from the local network, not just from the PC it's running on.

Comment: Is it not possible to bind the electron app to a host machine's public ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone will have the same question in the future, I'll post my solution. First of all, I've packed a build of react app into a zip archive. Then, I've included an archive as Embedded Resource into the project. Finally, I've used `Lexical.ZipFileProvider` as a `FileProvider` for `app.UseStaticFiles`. And voila, the thing just works!

Comment: So you firstly build the react app from nodejs, then zip it, then set that archive file as Embeded resource file, then VS build the exe?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. It is possible to automate the process by using some MSBuild commands or a shell script.